# tf.split with a tensor of size not divisible by the number of output tensors

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to parallelize my tensorflow code. At one point I need to run this to split the tensors.

```
    for variable_name, variable in kwargs.items():
            input_variables_split[variable_name] = tf.split(variable, number_of_devices)
```

The problem with this code is that tf.split expects that the 0th axis of all variables will be divisible by the number_of_devices, which might sometimes not be true in my case. What would be the best way to solve this?